# Time Series Database: 2 Bytes per Record?

Tags: database, unix, timestamp, time-series

I'm looking at this benchmark at https://blog.dataloop.io/time-series-database-benchmarks that shows databases like Dalmatiner, InfluxDB and Prometheus taking 1-2 bytes per record.

If you break down a unix timestamp into days since the epoch + seconds in the current day, then it would still take 2 bytes to store the seconds.

An example:

1479354563:False

How is it even possible to store a timestamp and a value in 2 bytes?

Comment: A `*ptr` ? As is this Q is too vague, you shouldn't expect people to go to external sites, you should include in your Q the relevant details from the remote site (and include a link for the terminally curious). Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is compression. See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HbnGSNEjhUc for how Prometheus does it for example.